# How to remove "Ã‚Â" from scraped in text in R?

Tags: r, special-characters, gsub

After I have scraped in some text "Ã‚Â" will be added after certain words and numbers in the text. To remove the unwanted "Ã‚Â" I have done a couple of gsubs.

```
text <- gsub("Ã", " ", text)
text <- gsub("Â", " ", text)
text <- gsub(",", "", text)
text <- gsub("  ", " ", text)
```

This works in removing the special characters A's but the comma is not taken out.

What text looks like before gsubs.

```
 ALBANYÃ‚Â OFFÃ‚Â REBOUND BY  #43Ã‚Â STIRE       #43Ã‚Â STIRE is not commented out
```

What text looks like after gsubs.

```
 ALBANY ‚  OFF ‚  REBOUND BY #43 ‚  STIRE        #43 ‚  STIRE is not commented out
```

What I would like the text to look like:

```
 ALBANY OFF REBOUND BY #43 STIRE                 #43 STIRE is not commented out
```

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Comment: Just do it in 1 `gsub()`: `gsub("Ã‚Â","","ALBANYÃ‚Â OFFÃ‚Â REBOUND BY")`

Comment: Instead of that, have you considered the possibility that you have some encoding faults in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `library(stringr)`

```
text <- "ALBANYÃ,Ã‚ OFFÃ,Ã‚ REBOUND BY"

library(stringr)
str_replace_all(text, "Ã,Ã‚", "")
#> [1] "ALBANY OFF REBOUND BY"
```

or with `gsub` :

```
gsub("Ã,Ã‚","",text)
#> [1] "ALBANY OFF REBOUND BY"
```

However, I think it is an encoding issue in the first place.
Moreover results of `gsub` or  `str_replace_all` may difer with encoding, it could be why your `text <- gsub(",", "", text)` do not work.

You could check encoding with `Encoding`.